# How to get a list of tuples from several text files?

Tags: python, pandas, information-retrieval

I want to access .txt files in 46 subdirectories and extract the number of 0s and 1s in the text of each file. So far I've written this code:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def count_0s(paths):
  for p in paths:
    list_zeros = []
    list_ones = []
    for line in p.read_text().splitlines():
      zeros = 0
      zeros += line.count('0')
      ones = 0
      ones += line.count('1')
    list_zeros.append(zeros)
    list_ones.append(ones)    
  return list_zeros, list_ones

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/"
paths = Path(path).glob("*/marked*.txt")
n_zeros=count_0s(paths)
n_zeros
```

I want to get the function return in the form of 2 lists (one with the number of 0s and the other with the number of 1s) to use in a Pandas dataframe.
Sorry if the questions are duplicated.

Comment: when you do `for i in count:`, you are already iterating over the elements, so you don't need `count[i]`. simply do `if i == '0':`. further try to add `print(i)` inside the loop and you'll be able to quickly identify the problem.

Comment: New and improved question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034689/how-to-get-a-list-of-tuples-from-several-text-files-part-2-electric-boogaloo

Answer (score 3):

There are couple mistakes in your function:

- you've added some unnecessary square brackets (`splitlines()` already returns a list)
- you don't iterate over characters, but over lines

Here is a corrected function:

```
def count_0s(paths):
  zeros_list = []
  ones_list = []
  for p in paths:
    zeros = 0
    ones = 0
    for line in p.read_text().splitlines():
        for c in line:
            if c == '0':
                zeros += 1
            else:
                ones += 1
    zeros_list.append(zeros)
    ones_list.append(ones)
  return zeros_list, ones_list
```

Be aware that this is probably a very inefficient way of counting 0 and 1. For example just using `line.count('0')` instead of a for loop can increase the speed by a factor of 10.

Comment: This way counts the 0s/1s and then sums them all into a final number. I want to have 46 tuples (1 for every subdirectory - and for each .txt file) and inside those tuples, I want to have the number of 0s and the number of 1s present in the text for the file that that tuple is assigned to.

Comment: initialize zeros and ones in the loop `for p in paths:`, add them to a list after `for line ...`, and return the list

Comment: It's still returning the total number of zeros and ones

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: I advise you to spend a bit more time figuring out by yourself why your code is not working. You'll learn much more quickly. You should also read those meta post, : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278064/my-code-isnt-working-clarification, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions I edited the code though.